# How do I write a DRF Serializer that combines four models with foreign keys?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Good afternoon,

I am confused about how to return the data I am after (or perhaps I have not set up the models efficiently).

My app has Users and Groups.  Each User is part of a group, each group has a leader and an ambassador (which are Users).  To accomplish this, I set up the following models:

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    group_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.group_name)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="group")


class Ambassadors(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ambassador")
    ambassador = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ambassador")


class GroupLeaders(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="leader")
    group_leader = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="leader")
```

What I would like to return are the group  fields along with the associated ID and name of the Ambassador and Leader for the group.

I created a serializer for the Ambassador & GroupLeaders Models, then added them to the Groups serializer, but I am not really understanding what steps to take an how to set this up.

Thanks for any guidance.

BCBB

Comment: First a modeling advice, if each group can have only one ambassador and one leader you should model them as `ForeignKey`s in the `Group ` model

Comment: yep... yep... yep....  Good call.  Not really sure what I was doing.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: However, if this for some reason was what I wanted, how would I do this?  Is there where a ManyToMany field comes into play?  Am I thinking to far down to the DB structure?    Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show your serializers' code